# How to copy NSData contents to temporary file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-s3

I'm downloading what can be a large file from an S3 bucket and want to save it between view controllers to be consumed a short time later.  I like the `tmp` directory because of less limitations on file size and there also does not seem to be a reason for me to save this in the Documents directory.

I can construct a path to `tmp` with:

```
        NSURL *tmpDirURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:NSTemporaryDirectory() isDirectory:YES];
        NSURL *fileURL = [[tmpDirURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"image"] URLByAppendingPathExtension:@"png"];
        NSLog(@"fileURL: %@", [fileURL path]);
```

but am unsure how to write/overwrite the downloaded `NSData *` to that path.

I basically just want to what I can more clearly express with the command line:

```
wget https://example.com/image.png
cp image.png /tmp/
```

Looks like the class reference may expose a method to do just this:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/

## EDIT

My solution that works.  Ended up being that I needed to use `writeToURL`.  Inspiration taken from here:
http://nshipster.com/nstemporarydirectory/
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURL/fileURLWithPath:isDirectory:

```
    #define S3_LATEST_IMAGE_FILEPATH   @"test-image.png"

    // Write the downloaded result to the filesystem
    NSError *error;
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%@", [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] globallyUniqueString], S3_LATEST_IMAGE_FILEPATH];
    NSURL *directoryURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] globallyUniqueString]] isDirectory:YES];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtURL:directoryURL withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error];
    if (error) {
      NSLog(@"Error1: %@", error);
      return;
    }
    NSURL *fileURL = [directoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    NSString *path = fileURL.absoluteString;
    NSLog(@"fileURL.absoluteString: %@", path);
    [data writeToURL:fileURL options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
    if (error) {
      NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can directly write the NSData into the path by

```
NSURL *tmpDirURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:NSTemporaryDirectory() isDirectory:YES];
NSURL *fileURL = [[tmpDirURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"newest-fw"] URLByAppendingPathExtension:@"zip"];
NSString *path= fileURL.absoluteString;
//data would be the NSData that you get from the S3 bucket
NSError *error;
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtURL: fileURL withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
[data writeToFile:path options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
```

NSData's writeToFile method will automatically overwrite the file if it is previously present.

Comment: I'm getting error: `Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The file "image.png” doesn’t exist." UserInfo={NSFilePath=file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/809801E6-94AD-4EEA-91D1-6C74155E9396/tmp/image.ping, NSUnderlyingError=0x146dd6760 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}`

Comment: If your path contains any new directories then you have to create the directories first before writing.  I have updated my answer please check

Comment: Hmm.  I was looking at that to.  Doesn't solve it.  The file is definitely also being created at the root of the tmp directory (no subdirectories in the way).

Comment: you get this error because of the line: [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtURL: fileURL withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error]; this uses the filename and creates a directory with the same name.